# Pause the calling another activity from one activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I have some code to call an Activity from the main activity

```
Button btnAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
EditText Name =((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1));

public void onClick(View view) {

  if (name1 != "")
  {
    Intent startSub = new Intent(MainActivity.this,activity2.class);
    startSub.putExtra("name", name1);
    startActivity(startSub);
  } else {
    Nm.setError("Enter Name");
  }
}
```

My problem is when I click the button with out entering the name, its launching   the next Activity (even i put intent in if statement).
But I want to stick with this Activity until i enter the name .

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
name1 != ""
```

will always be true because != does not compare Strings but the object references. Those are not equal for name1 and "".

You need to use equals() to compare Strings equality in a useful way:

```
if (!"".equals(name1)) {
```

or in this case: TextUtils.isEmpty(CharSequence str) is even better because it also is true if name1 is null:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name1)) {
```